# Problem with C char[] swapping

Tags: c, char, swap

I have this short code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fastSwap (char **i, char **d)
{
    char *t = *d;
    *d = *i;
    *i = t;
}
int main ()
{
    char num1[] = "hello";
    char num2[] = "class";
    fastSwap ((char**)&num1,(char**)&num2);
    printf ("%s\n",num1);
    printf ("%s\n",num2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this short program is:

```
claso
hells
```

and I just don't understand why the last letters of each char[] are swapped.
Any ideas?

Comment: something feels very wrong about your snippet. can you please tell us what you were trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 5):

```
fastSwap ((char**)&num1,(char**)&num2);
```

This is undefined behavior. You can't cast a pointer to array of char to a pointer to pointer to char. What you need is:

```
const char* num1 = "hello";
const char* num2 = "class";
fastSwap (&num1,&num2);
```

Also, you'll need to change the declaration of `fastSwap` and add inner-level `const` to arguments

```
void fastSwap (const char **i, const char **d)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to swap the *contents* of the `num1` and `num2` arrays by just manipulating pointers, so that after calling `fastswap` the contents of `num1` will be `"class"` and `num2` will be `"hello"`.

If that's the case, then this won't work for a number of reasons.  Arrays are not pointers, even though array *expressions* are often converted to pointer types.  Secondly, you cannot modify the value of an array expression.

If you want to keep `num1` and `num2` as arrays (as opposed to pointers to string literals) and be able to swap their contents, you'll need to something more along these lines:

```
void fastswap(char *i, char *d)
{
  while (*i && *d)
  {
    char t = *i;
    *d++ = *i;
    *i++ = t;
  }
}
```

which will be called as

```
fastswap(num1, num2);
```

Comment: Array are not pointers?
I thought that "char str[]" points to the beginning of the array, so shouldn't it be a pointer?

Comment: Depending on where that `char str[]` declaration appears, it may denote an array or a pointer.  As a *function parameter*, it declares a pointer.  Anywhere else, it declares an array of unknown size; if there's an initializer that immediately follows the declaration, then the size of the array is taken from that.  In most circumstances, an array *expression* will have its type converted from "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`", but that's not the same thing as an array *being* a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing pointers to pointers to chars. You probably just want to pass pointers to chars like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fastSwap (char *i, char *d)
{
    char t = *d;
    *d = *i;
    *i = t;
}
int main ()
{
    char num1[] = "hello";
    char num2[] = "class";
    fastSwap (num1,num2);
    printf ("%s\n",num1);
    printf ("%s\n",num2);
    return 0;
}
```

This swaps the first character of the 2 char arrays.

Comment: You honestly think that this was his intention?